# Save local image on my phone to a computer through IP address

Tags: flutter, ip

I have a Flutter app that allows the user to pick a photo from his gallery, after that I wanted to send that image to my PC through IP address and save it there. Is this possible?

Comment: This is really too broad for a single question. Please clarify what *exactly* you need help with. What *can* you do right now and where is the point where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://pub.dev/packages/get_ip#-readme-tab-
AND this: https://pub.dev/packages/get_ip#-example-tab-

These should enable you to send a flutter selected file to your pc using your ip address. You may need to set-up a mini vpn on your homw/office router and identify your own computer using a vpn ip submask within your master ip address, but not necessarily.

Comment: Hey, I checked the links you gave me but they only help me get the ip address of a certain machine, which I already have.I am trying to send and image (probably through an http request) from my phone to another machine which has some kind of server side code that decodes the image.

Comment: Those packages are not relevant to the question. The OP is not looking for their own device's IP address.